# How to get node selected insted of the root?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am using wx.TreeCtrl and create a tree,similar to this:

Root = "C:\"

Child of root

Node 1 = A

Node 2 = B

Then I am using this event to get the node selected.

self.Tree.Bind( wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnTreeSelChanged, 
id=self.Tree.GetId())

```
def OnTreeSelChanged(self, event):
    itemID = event.GetItem()  # using this or this:
    tree_ctrl = event.EventObject 
    itemID1 = tree_ctrl.GetSelection()
    old_pydata = tree_ctrl.GetItemData(itemID)
    old_pydata1 = tree_ctrl.GetItemData(itemID1 )
```

What happen is that if I select the Node A the firts Item that I get selected is always the root (i.e. "C:\" insted of Node A). I need to be able to get the node selected and this dont happen I cant understand why, after the first selection it seems to work properlly again. However if I change the root node I willget again the same problem.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Can you post a small, runnable example application?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the wx.TreeCtrl has some bugs, i changed to the import wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl and this dont happen anymore.